# How do you run an application as TrustedInstaller or SYSTEM without using external programs?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, runas, application-launch

Using only the Command Prompt and/or PowerShell, but without external programs or commands, how can you run an application as TrustedInstaller or SYSTEM?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no simple way to log in as *SYSTEM* or as *TrustedInstaller* without using third-party tools such as Microsoft's own (well, actually Russinovich's Sysinternals') [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), Nirsoft's [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) or Sordum's [PowerRun](https://www.sordum.org/9416/powerrun-v1-4-run-with-highest-privileges/).

It is easy, however, to make use of these tools *appear* to be native to Windows GUI, i.e., as a context menu item for executables, with a [Registry tweak that adds the particular tool to the right-click menu](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-program-as-system-localsystem-account-windows/).

[Even with those privileges, at times it may be impossible to perform simple tasks, such as using *Regedit* to modify a key owned by *TrustedInstaller*, without taking ownership.]

Comment: Putting aside that I don't know how you could be so sure about an actually nonexistent user, *TrustedInstaller* can be run as with [Process Hacker](https://borncity.com/win/2017/02/22/windows-10-execute-programs-as-systemtrustedinstaller/).

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2017/08/the-art-of-becoming-trustedinstaller.html, here are the steps I try in my machine

1. Open your powershell (as administrator)
2. PS> Install-Module -Name NtObjectManager
3. PS> Start-Service -Name TrustedInstaller
4. PS> $parent = Get-NtProcess -ServiceName TrustedInstaller
5. PS> $proc = New-Win32Process cmd.exe  -CreationFlags NewConsole -ParentProcess $parent

Notes:
`Install-Module` only need run once to import module. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NtObjectManager/

After step-5 new command prompt will open, in there we can check by running `whoami` it will show `nt authority\system`

Comment: So why doesn't running `whoami` return `nt authority\trustedinstaller`? I was under the impression System and TrustedInstaller were different "users," with the latter having greater privileges than the former?

Comment: UPDATE: after some cursory googling, I guess System is the *account*, while TrustedInstaller is a set of *privileges* that the account *can* have (but doesn't always, e.g. if a System process were launched from PsExec). Is that more or less correct?

Answer (score 1):

BTW, here's a .ps1 script made out of [@hasto's commands](https://superuser.com/a/1781731/167207):

```
$ConfirmPreference = "None"
$isAdmin = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
if (-not $isAdmin) {
    Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs
    exit
}
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy bypass
Install-Module -Name NtObjectManager
Start-Service -Name TrustedInstaller
$parent = Get-NtProcess -ServiceName TrustedInstaller
$proc = New-Win32Process cmd.exe -CreationFlags NewConsole -ParentProcess $parent
$ConfirmPreference = "High"
```